# Jenkins behind apache proxy

Tags: apache, jenkins, kubernetes, proxy, reverse-proxy

My Jenkins is running in Kubernetes with Service type: LoadBalancer, and added below azure annotations to take internal subnet private ip address to expose service internally.

```
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: subnetName
```

I've one ubuntu VM where Apache is installed. Created self signed certificated and terminated in apache configurations, and I'm able to access apache home page using HTTPS.

Then I've created proxy rule to Jenkins service IP address. Basically I want to access Jenkins from Apache HTTPS --> to internally HTTP traffic towards kubernetes service.

Here is Apache configurations:

```
xxxx@xxxx:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls -ltrh
total 28K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1332 Jul 16 18:14 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6338 Jul 16 18:14 default-ssl.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 12 17:24 abc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  680 Dec 12 13:04 abc.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 12 14:29 xyz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1151 Dec 12 13:08 xyz.conf

cat abc/00-redirect-to-https.conf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^jenkins$ login [L,R=302]


cat abc.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/abc_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/abc_access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For
      RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Host
      RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Server
      RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
      RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "80"
    </IfModule>

    # Apache will try to set application/json based on mime type
    # This behaviour casing problems with empty json responses from spring
    RemoveType json

    Include sites-available/abc/*.conf
</VirtualHost>


cat xyz/00-jenkins.conf
ProxyPass /jenkins balancer://jenkins/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins balancer://jenkins/jenkins
<Proxy balancer://jenkins>
    BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8080 loadfactor=1 keepalive=On retry=0
    ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
</Proxy>


cat xyz.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName FQDN

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xyz_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xyz_access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For
      RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Host
      RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Server
      RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
      RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    </IfModule>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/certs/ca.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/ca.key


    # Apache will try to set application/json based on mime type
    # This behaviour casing problems with empty json responses from spring
    RemoveType json

    Include sites-available/xyz/*.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

If I do `curl -k https://localhost/jenkins` from local ubuntu VM then response shows that authentication required which is fine as below, but redirecting url becomes `window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F')`

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fjenkins'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fjenkins');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

But with the same case, when I request from browser `https://FQDN/jenkins` again URL becomes `https://FQDN/login?from=%2F` But there browser throws URL Not found error

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Please assist here to correct the configurations..

Thanks..

More observation from logs:

when I did `curl -k https://localhost/jenkins` apache access logs shows 403 which is ok because I've not passed credentials

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2019:13:37:40 +0000] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 403 3297 "-" "curl/7.58.0"
```

and when same tried from internet browser `https://FQDN/jenkins` apache logs first shows 403 which is wanted but soon after apache tries to find changed url in same VM instead of redirecting, due to which i'm not getting jenkins page.

```
165.225.106.137 - - [13/Dec/2019:13:38:19 +0000] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 403 3446 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"

165.225.106.137 - - [13/Dec/2019:13:38:19 +0000] "GET /jenkins HTTP/1.1" 403 1564 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"

165.225.106.137 - - [13/Dec/2019:13:38:20 +0000] "GET /login?from=%2F HTTP/1.1" 404 541 "https://DNSname/jenkins" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: is FQDN in `https://FQDN/jenkins` stands for that UbuntuVM's  FQDN? Are you able to reach any other page hosted on Ubuntu VM from browser on external host?

Comment: @Nick yes FQDN is UbuntuVM's FQDN. I've tried calling https://FQDN which is working fine, and yes 've placed one test.html in /var/www/html/test.html and it's responding by calling https://FQDN/test.html from external host

Comment: not sure if  `ProxyPass /jenkins balancer://jenkins/jenkins` shall match `<Proxy balancer://jenkins>`,  So /jenkins  will go to  `http://x.x.x.x:8080/jenkins/jenkins`  . need to check that.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your replies.. I've found the solution, please find below posted in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now after changing below configurations --

(1)
`Set the context path by modifying the jenkins.xml configuration file and adding --prefix=/jenkins (or similar) to the <arguments> entry.`

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache

(2) 
Initially -- `RewriteRule ^jenkins$ login [L,R=302]`
Now -- `RewriteRule ^/jenkins(.*)$ /`

(3)
Initially --

```
ProxyPass /jenkins balancer://jenkins/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins balancer://jenkins/jenkins
<Proxy balancer://jenkins>
    BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8080 loadfactor=1 keepalive=On retry=0
    ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
</Proxy>
```

Now --

```
ProxyPass /jenkins balancer://jenkins
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins balancer://jenkins
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
<Proxy balancer://jenkins>
    BalancerMember http://x.x.x.x:8080/jenkins loadfactor=1 keepalive=On retry=0
    ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
</Proxy>
```

Comment: well done. I have noticed that the load balancer config was looking incorrect ( official doc on [mod_proxy_balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)) but it was only a part of the issue.